# Series of Legendre Polynomials and Harmonic numbers. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_n (z) \frac{H(n)}{n+k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, legendre-polynomials, legendre-functions

I would like to compute sums of the type

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_n (z) \frac{H(n)}{n+k}
\end{equation}

where $P_n(z)$ are Legendre polynomials, $H(n)$ are harmonic numbers and $k = 0, 1, 2, 3...$, a positive integer.

I've tried using the integral representation for $H(n)$ and then the generator function for legendre polynomials. Moreover, I tried using the integral representation for legendre polynomials, but it seems that nothing works...

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think in general this isn't going to have a closed form.

Comment: @K.defaoite I already found a closed form for k=0,1. The problem is that it's quite ugly, so I think that there is a smarter way of computing it. In fact, I have to compute $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_{n}(z) \frac{H(n)}{(n+k)^\alpha}
$$
for $\alpha$ a positive integer.